# python: load function from external file dynamically

Tags: python-3.x

I have my function defined in an external file named `ext.py`:

```
def show(message):
    print('message is: ', message)
```

I need to load this function dynamically in the sense that as soon as I changed the content of `ext.py`, the newly changed show function get loaded (overwrite the previous definition). `main.py`:

```
import time

while True:
    import ext
    ext.show("test")
    time.sleep(5)
```

problem is that if I change the definition of `show` function in `ext.py` (while `main.py` is running) and save the file on itself, the new changes won't show up and `main.py` still uses the old definition.

For example (new `ext.py` while `main.py` is running):

```
def show(message):
    print('NEW message is: ', message)
```

The result still is:

```
message is: ###
```

Comment: That's quite tricky to pull off. I'd suggest something like this: Use `inotifywait` to listen for changes to `ext.py`, when the change notification is triggered, send a signal to your running `main.py` process, in the signal handler for that signal in `main.py`, use `importlib.reload` to reload the whole `ext` module.

Comment: `importlib.reload` solved the problem. Thanks.